# Java null arguments when chaining Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, copy-constructor

Let's say I have a class with multiple constructors, one of which is a copy-constructor (to copy an object):

```
public class Rectangle {

    int width, height;

    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
        this(source.width, source.height);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make check if `source` is `null` in the copy-constructor and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it is? Because the other constructor call **has** to be the first statement in my constructor.

Comment: Why does the other constructor call have to be the first statement in the copy constructor?

Comment: Because that's what Java wants.

Comment: @Janno: Because that's how Java works. You can't use `this(...)` after another statement.

Comment: I would leave it as NPE when a `null` is passed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
     this(checkNotNull(source, "Source cannot be null").width, source.height);
}

private static <T> T checkNotNull(T t, String msg) {
    if (t == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    return t;
}
```

I also agree with Jon Skeet that a `NullPointerException` is not a bad bevahiour in this case. The only thing is that in long lines when you get an NPE it can be a bit hard to identify which object is `null`, which is why a more specific message can be useful.

You can also not reinvent the wheel and use standard `java.util.Objects` methods if you don't bother throwing a `NullPointerException` instead:

```
public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
     this(Objects.requireNonNull(source, "Source cannot be null").width, source.height);
}
```

if your error message is expensive to build, you can provide a `Supplier<String>` instead, to pay the cost of the construction of the message only when it's actually needed:

```
 public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
     this(Objects.requireNonNull(source, () -> explainError(source)).width, source.height);
}
```

Comment: checkNotNull method should return a value of type 'T'.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use a helper method which will throw the exception if necessary, and return the original value otherwise... you can call that within your constructor invocation, as you're allow method calls as part of argument evaluation.

```
// In a helper class
public static <T> T checkNotNull(T value) {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Then use it as:

```
public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
    this(Helper.checkNotNull(source).width, source.height);
}
```

However... I believe that `NullPointerException` is the recommended exception to throw here anyway (in Effective Java 2nd edition, for example), which your existing code will throw already. So you quite possibly *don't* want to make any change to your existing code.

If you want a helper method for checks like this but are happy for it to throw `NullPointerException`, I'd recommend using Guava and its [Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java) class, which has this and a *lot* of other helpful checking methods.

Also note that Java 1.7 introduced [`java.util.Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) which has `requireNonNull`, so you don't even need a third party library.

Comment: Is `NullPointerException` relly the way to go? I thought to have seen `IllegalArgumentException` to be thrown is such a situation before.

Comment: @kalsowerus `java.util.Objects.requireNonNull` throws a `NullPointerException`, so yeah that's ok. Check out my answer for seeing a few examples ( after I edit it)

Comment: @kalsowerus NPE means that you used a `null` value when you should have used a reference to an object.

Comment: @kalsowerus: NullPointerException is recommended by Josh Bloch, and is what Google's style guide uses. That's my main source of truth on these things :)

Comment: @Dici: Ooh, I hadn't seen `Objects.requireNonNull`. Will edit that in here.

Comment: @kalsowerus IMHO : both extend `RuntimeException` so it will not change the behavior but using `IllegalArgumentException` changes the semantic which is not good for code readability.

Answer (score 3):

One text-book trick is move the initialization out of the constructor to a method. Then, you can have whatever code you want before it:

```
public class Rectangle {

    int width, height;

    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        init(width, height);
    }

    public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
        if (source == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("source can't be null!");
        }
        init(source.width, source.height);
    }

    private void init(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that that means `width` and `height` can't be final, which is often a very significant downside.

Comment: ALso, `private final` is redundant since `private` methods cannot be seen from the subclasses

Comment: @Dici yup, that's true, removed the `final`.

Comment: @JonSkeet interesting point about this technique prohibiting the members from being final. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you really do want to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, I think the cleanest solution is to use a static method instead of a constructor:

```
public static Rectangle from(Rectangle source) {
    if (source == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("source can't be null!");
    }
    return new Rectangle(source.width, source.height);
}
```

Or you could just add a copy method:

```
public Rectangle copy() {
    return new Rectangle(this.width, this.height);
}
```

I'd prefer the latter, since it removes the need to concern yourself with the Rectangle possibly being null. Note that this will cause a NPE if you use this with a null Object, which is possibly a further indication that an NPE is fine.

Comment: Note that the `copy`-approach may be problematic in case of inheritance -  all subclasses would *have* to override this in order to avoid unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
int width, height;

public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
   if(source != null) {
      width = source.width;
      height = source.height;
   }
}
```

Comment: He wanted to avoid code duplication by calling into the base constructor and throw a validation exception. This code meets neither of these two requirements

Comment: Ah ok,thanks a lot. I'm sorry but it's my first answer on here.

Comment: No worries :). Good journey on Stack Overflow